# Double start onAnimationEnd on Android

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to create a sort of slide show. For this I need to make the loop the animation with the change of the image at the end of each animation. But for whatever reason, the same event occurs twice per animation

```
public cPhotoSlide(Activity _activity, DBHelper _helper, int idMenu, cItemViewer _ItemViewer){
    activity        = _activity;
    helper          = _helper;
    ImageManager    = helper.ImageManager;
    ItemViewer      = _ItemViewer;
    cursor          = 0;        
    itemIds         = ChildsItemsToTable(idMenu);
    MainLayout      = (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.fon);
    SliderObj       = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.photo_slide, MainLayout, true);
    SlideImage      = (ImageView) SliderObj.findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
    SlideImage.setImageBitmap(ImageManager.loadImage(activity.getApplicationContext(),itemIds.get(cursor)));

    animationSlide  = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide);

    animationSlide.getAnimations().get(1).setAnimationListener(
            new AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Cursor = "+cursor+"/"+itemIds.size());
                    if (cursor >= itemIds.size()-1) {
                        cursor = 0;
                    } else {
                        cursor += 1;
                    }
                    if (itemIds.get(cursor).content != 0) {
                        SlideImage.setImageBitmap(ImageManager.loadImage(itemIds.get(cursor)));
                    }
                    SlideImage.startAnimation(animationSlide);
                }
            }
    );

    SlideImage.startAnimation(animationSlide);
}
```

In XML:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0">
    </alpha>
    <alpha
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

in log:

```
01-30 15:52:26.700: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 0/207
01-30 15:52:26.716: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 1/207
01-30 15:52:28.990: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 2/207
01-30 15:52:29.005: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 3/207
01-30 15:52:31.279: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 4/207
01-30 15:52:31.302: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 5/207
01-30 15:52:33.575: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 6/207
01-30 15:52:33.591: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 7/207
01-30 15:52:35.865: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 8/207
01-30 15:52:35.888: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 9/207
01-30 15:52:38.161: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 10/207
01-30 15:52:38.177: D/cPhotoSlide(22301): Cursor = 11/207
```

Comment: I haven't seen your problem in your snippets. How do you conclude that onAnimationEnd() is fired twice?

Comment: @class-stacker I defined it in timings of the log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your animationset consists of two animations , and your code is being called by each one of them, to fix this you can do this:

```
animationSlide.getAnimations().get(1).setAnimationListener(.....);
```

insted of

```
animationSlide.setAnimationListener(.....);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong to loading this animation
`animationSlide  = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide);`
because now the animation is immediately closes, ignoring:
`android:startOffset="2000"`

Comment: Posted all constructor of this class

Comment: Please don't set ImageBitmap and set the imageview size in the layout xml ,  android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

Comment: Strange, but problem was solved after adding `android:startOffset = "100"` to first animation

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this was to change from **.setAnimationListener** to **.withEndAction**

Example:

```
 my_button.animate()
     .setDuration(10)
     .scaleX(1)
     .scaleY(1)
     .withEndAction(() -> (your action goes here) ).start();
```

> Explanation:

.withEndAction() is runnable gets removed after it was started. So The Runnable is just executed once and the Listener might be called multiple times.

Comment: This works, however be aware that, `the action is only run if the animation ends normally; if the ViewPropertyAnimator is canceled during that animation, the runnable will not run.` So if for example views should be enabled after an animation, this is not a good place to do it because execution is not guaranteed.